# Concatenate two Func delegates

Tags: c#, lambda, concatenation, func

I have this Class:

```
public class Order
{
   int OrderId {get; set;}
   string CustomerName {get; set;}
}
```

I declare below variables, too

```
Func<Order, bool> predicate1 = t=>t.OrderId == 5 ;
Func<Order, bool> predicate2 = t=>t.CustomerName == "Ali";
```

Is there any way that concatenate these variables(with AND/OR) and put the result in 3rd variable?
for example:

```
Func<Order, bool> predicate3 = predicate1 and predicate2;
```

or

```
Func<Order, bool> predicate3 = predicate1 or predicate2;
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

And:

```
Func<Order, bool> predicate3 = 
    order => predicate1(order) && predicate2(order);
```

Or:

```
Func<Order, bool> predicate3 = 
    order => predicate1(order) || predicate2(order);
```

Comment: This needs to be higher up in search results since all of the top answers require screwing around with Expression types.